# How can I split my model among multiple GPUs?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, gpt-2

I have been trying to split the `self.blocks` among multiple GPUs, but it returns the error "All tensors must be on same GPU." I don't want DataParallel, but ModelParallel among 2 GPU minimum and their weights and biases should commute with each other.

```
class LanguageModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # each token directly reads off the logits for the next token from a lookup table
        self.token_embedding_table = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, n_embd)
        self.position_embedding_table = nn.Embedding(block_size, n_embd)
        self.blocks = nn.DataParallel(nn.Sequential(*[Block(n_embd, n_head) for _ in range(n_layer)]))
        self.ln_f = nn.LayerNorm(n_embd) # final layer norm
        self.lm_head = nn.Linear(n_embd, vocab_size)

        # better init, not covered in the original GPT video, but important, will cover in followup video
        self.apply(self._init_weights)

    def _init_weights(self, module):
        if isinstance(module, nn.Linear):
            torch.nn.init.normal_(module.weight, mean=0.0, std=0.02)
            if module.bias is not None:
                torch.nn.init.zeros_(module.bias)
        elif isinstance(module, nn.Embedding):
            torch.nn.init.normal_(module.weight, mean=0.0, std=0.02)

    def forward(self, idx, targets=None):
        B, T = idx.shape
        # idx and targets are both (B,T) tensor of integers
        tok_emb = self.token_embedding_table(idx) # (B,T,C)
        pos_emb = self.position_embedding_table(torch.arange(T, device=device[0])) # (T,C)
        x = tok_emb + pos_emb # (B,T,C)
        x = self.blocks(x) # (B,T,C)
        x = self.ln_f(x) # (B,T,C)
        logits = self.lm_head(x) # (B,T,vocab_size)

        if targets is None:
            loss = None
        else:
            B, T, C = logits.shape
            logits = logits.view(B*T, C)
            targets = targets.view(B*T)
            loss = F.cross_entropy(logits, targets)

        return logits, loss

    def generate(self, idx, max_new_tokens):
        # idx is (B, T) array of indices in the current context
        for _ in range(max_new_tokens):
            # crop idx to the last block_size tokens
            idx_cond = idx[:, -block_size:]
            # get the predictions
            logits, loss = self(idx_cond)
            # focus only on the last time step
            logits = logits[:, -1, :] # becomes (B, C)
            # apply softmax to get probabilities
            probs = F.softmax(logits, dim=-1) # (B, C)
            # sample from the distribution
            idx_next = torch.multinomial(probs, num_samples=1) # (B, 1)
            # append sampled index to the running sequence
            idx = torch.cat((idx, idx_next), dim=1) # (B, T+1)
        return idx
```

I have already tried splitting it like

```
# splitting blocks into multiple GPUs
      for i in range(n_layer):
      self.blocks.module[i].to(device[i % len(device)])
```

Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use among 2 gpu minimum you need to use nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel
Documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel.html

```
import torch.distributed as dist
import torch.nn.parallel


model = nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(model, device_ids=[rank], output_device=rank)
```